# Adding a Entity Data Model to my project and then get 'The type or namespace name 'SetInitializer' does not exist in namespace/missing reference error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm getting this error below on my new MVC 4 project.

> The type or namespace name 'SetInitializer' does not exist in the namespace 'NFLN_Foundation.Database' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   C:...\Filters\InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs

All I'm doing is adding a new file ADO.NET Entity Data Model --> EF Designer from Database.. and have tried LINQ to SQL as well.. and it adds everything just fine.  But once I run the project, I get that error I stated above.  I can't seem to find a solution that works when i Google search.

I've tried upgrading to the latest Entity Framework (6.0) and still the same error.  What's going on??

It's erroring in this specific line here:

```
    private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
    {
        public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);  //This line is erroring, specifically the SetInitializer
```

I mean.. that file it's erroring is an auto-generated file too that comes with the project, I just don't understand why i'm getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

sigh okay changing the last line to:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);
```

worked for me.